# True time comparison returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This:

```
puts send_time
puts DateTime.now.to_time
puts send_time === DateTime.now.to_time
```

Returns this:

```
2014-07-29 12:14:00 -0400
2014-07-29 12:14:00 -0400
false
```

Is this rails bug or am I missing something?

Comment: what is `send_time`? Is it `Time` or `DateTime` or `Date` class?

Comment: @RAJ... `send_time` is a `Time` that was converted from a `DateTime` using `to_time`

Comment: what about `puts send_time.to_s === DateTime.now.to_time.to_s`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Works! Write it as an answer and I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `puts` method calls an implicit `.to_s` on the code being displayed. This is probably causing the error:

```
puts send_time.to_s === DateTime.now.to_time.to_s
```

Should return `true`

And the following:

```
puts send_time.to_time == DateTime.now.to_time
```

Should return `true` also (only two equals, not three)